# Unable to update User games property when user creaties a new game mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm working on an app where users can create and account and make trivia games. `User` has a property called `games` which is a collection of `Game` id's that that `User` instance has created. When I create a `Game` instance, before I return the response (`JSON` of new `Game` instance), I find the `User` instance and use a `User` schema method to add the newly created `Games` id to the collection of game ids in the `User`'s games property. It seems to work when I create a game, I was able to log the instance of `User` with the array reflecting the newly added `Game` id.

But then when I try to get the `User` via `localhost:4000/users/USER_ID` the `games` property remains empty.

Here is my `User` Model.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let User = new Schema({
  username: {
     type: String, required: true, trim: true, default: null,
     unique: true
  },
  password: {
     type: String, required: true, trim: true, default: null
  },
  games:{
     type: Array, required: false, default: []
  }
});

User.methods.addGame = async function(id) {
  const user = this;
  var games = user.games;
  games.push(id);
  user.games = games;
  user.save()
  return user
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Here is my root `/users` route and my `/users/:id` route.

```
userRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res){
  User.find(function(err, users){
    if(err){
       res.status(400).send(err);
    } else {
       res.json(users)
    }
  });
});

userRoutes.route('/:id').get(function(req, res){
   User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user){
     if(err){
       res.status(400).send(err)
     } else {
       if (user){
          res.status(200).json(user);
       } else {
          res.status(400).send('user not found :(')
       } 
    }
  });
});
```

And here is my `add` game route.

```
gameRoutes.route('/add').post( async function(req, res){
  try {
    var user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.body.owner })
    let game = new Game(req.body);
    if (!user){
      res.status(400).send('user not found.')
    } else {
      await game.save()
      await user.addGame(game._id);
      if (!game){
        res.status(400).send('game cannot be created');
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(game);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Finally, here is the data that is logged when I use `mongoose.set('debug', true)` and create a game.

```
 Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5daca0171febbb25f2c929dd") }, 
 { projection: {} })
 Mongoose: games.insertOne({ questions: [ { id: 0, qTitle: 'When is 
 Independence Day?', qAnswers: [ { aId: 0, aContent: 'July 18th' }, { 
 aId: 1, aContent: 'July 19th' }, { aId: 2, aContent: 'July 30th' }, { 
 aId: 3, aContent: 'July 4th' } ], answer: 3, correct: null }, { id: 1, 
 qTitle: 'When is Christmas Day?', qAnswers: [ { aId: 0, aContent: 
 'July 18th' }, { aId: 1, aContent: 'July 19th' }, { aId: 2, aContent: 
 'December 25th' }, { aId: 3, aContent: 'December 31st' } ], answer: 2, 
 correct: null } ], qTime: null, expDate: null, isPrivate: true, 
 isClosed: false, _id: ObjectId("5db5c2fe96960e318ae8f60f"), name: 
 'poppie', __v: 0 }, { session: null })
 Mongoose: users.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("5daca0171febbb25f2c929dd"), 
 __v: 19 }, { '$set': { games: [ ObjectId("5db5c2fe96960e318ae8f60f") ] 
 }, 
 '$inc': { __v: 1 } }, { session: undefined })
```

Right after creating a game, if I go to `/localhost:4000/users` I see the resulting list of `User`'s.

```
 [{
    "username": "matt_cee",
    "password": 
    "$2a$10$/ySrwkMxaHGO24FOEst3NuqpG4iQi78BUCSkl4Hb.RmjTIwynR3l.",
    "games": [
        "5db5c2fe96960e318ae8f60f"
    ]
  }]
```

As you can see, the `games` array contains the newly created game's id. I am able to log the updated `User` in the `/add` games route but when accessing the `/:id` user route, the returned `User` instance has an empty array for the games property.

Comment: ```mongoose.set('debug', true)``` is your friend. Depending on mongoose version you should have to ```user.markModified('games')``` before saving

Comment: @user753642 thanks for the comment. I just made the changes and it looks like now. I also made my `User` model property `games` be an array of `objectId`'s. I can get the game id's for the user when I make the get request to `/users` but when I make the request to `users/ USER_ID` the games array is empty. Any idea why it would update the user at one route but not the other?

Comment: there is no route ```/users``` in the code you provided. Did you want to refer to ```/add```? Btw you don't synchronize ```game.save``` but still return the ```game``` on the success condition of ```user.save``` (this is bad). If you return a ```game```, return your saved ```game```. Just check in base or again via ```mongoose.set('debug', true)``` that your player was correctly saved. EDIT: and do not let the hypothetic failure of game.save disappear in the wind as an ```unhandledPromiseRejection```

Comment: I did not include the `/users` route because it's a simple `GET` for all the users and I didn't think it would be relevant but I just added it now. `/add` is a `Game` route. As I was saying, I think the `/add` route is updating the `user` properly because when I get the user via `/users` I can see the added game id. But when I try to get that inividual user `/users/:id` the `games` property is still empty. What do you mean by synchronize `game.save()`? I also thought the `if (!game){...}` statement was sufficient for error handling.

Comment: as you ```await person.save```, you should do so as well for ```game.save``` (actually all the more). Maybe you failed to save the game but still saved the reference onto user. Then by some obscure plugin, the find do not hydrate the games, but the ```findById``` tries to and by failing to hydrate the game, consider the array as empty. This is highly hypothetic and you should confirm that the ```game``` was saved successfully. (I don't think I can help further more if no minimalist reproducible example). edit: you should defintely add the logs of ```mongoose.set('debug', true)``` upon saving.

Comment: @user753642 sorry I've been busy the last few days. I updated the code to include what `mongoose.set('debug', true)` is logging. I also added `await` for `game.save()`. This line `users.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("5daca0171febbb25f2c929dd"), 
 __v: 19 }, { '$set': { games: [ ObjectId("5db5c2fe96960e318ae8f60f") ] 
 }` leads me to believe the user is being updated and that is reflected when I access `localhost:4000/users` but not when I access `localhost:4000/users/5daca0171febbb25f2c929dd`

Comment: @user753642 I actually just figured it out. The issue was with how I was setting the `owner` for the `Game` instance. I probably should've included the `Game` model but I forgot I made the `owner` property an object that contains the user's `ObjectId` AND `username`, but when I created the game I was only passing the `ObjectId` so the owner was not being set properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue was that I wasn't providing the property in the right format. Here is how my `Game` model was set up.

```
let Game = new Schema({
    owner: { 
          id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "User"
          },
          username: {type: String}
        }
    },
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    questions: {
        type: Array
    }
});
```

The problem was I was trying to update the `User` by adding the id of the newly created `Game` to `user.games` but the owner property wasn't populating properly because I was only passing the `user`'s id not the username. Below is my updated game model.

```
let Game = new Schema({
   owner: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true
   },
   name:{
      type: String
   },
   questions: {
      type: Array
   }
```

})

Special thanks to [@user753642](https://stackoverflow.com/users/753642/user753642) with who's help I was able to better structure my code and debug the data.